# Adobe Air: how to use f2, f3, f4 in keyEquivalent when making menu

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, adobe, air

i need 1 help i have a trouble while making menu in adobe air i want to use f2, f3, f4 shortcut, but when i use keyEquivalent = 'f2' property it showing in the menu but not working.

when i press f2 it does not work but when i press f it works it means it just taking first character does any one can solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Adobe BugBase](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=2906648), it's a bug that won't be fixed for "near future release". Something similar was mentioned two years back at this link: [Flex SDK Bugs](http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-17901?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3aall-tabpanel). So I'm afraid it seems to be a dead-end at the moment.

Comment: KeyboardEvent is working good i know that i am asking about keyEquivalent for adobe air NativeMenu which does not work u have given me answer does not have any relation ship with this

Comment: Updated my answer to better match your, clarified, question.